# Float the editing window

Tags: feature-request, questions, draft

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Question and preview might be better side-by-side](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70703/question-and-preview-might-be-better-side-by-side)

#### Problem

Sometimes if your post is long and has images, [it is tedious to scroll down to see the preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFPho.png).

#### Suggestion:

Perhaps a **side-by-side format**, for *wide-screen monitors*:

[image: ss]

or

maybe it would be better to have an option to float the editing window, *or* float the preview window.

Comment: Here's a feature request to use the [Discourse layout for side-by-side Markdown preview](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253112/the-discourse-layout-for-side-by-side-markdown-preview).